# Dataframe transformations produce empty values

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have been trying to list all the Spark dataframes from Parquet files in directories except metadata directory.
The structure of directories looks like this:

```
dumped_data/
 - time=19424145
 - time=19424146
 - time=19424147
 - _spark_metadata
```

The main goal is to avoid reading data from _spark_metadata directory. I have created a solution but it constantly returns empty values for some reason. What could be the reason of it?

Here is the solution:

```
 val dirNamesRegex: Regex = s"\\_spark\\_metadata*".r

def transformDf: Option[DataFrame] = {
 val filesDf = listPath(new Path(feedPath))(fsConfig)
      .map(_.getName)
      .filter(name => !dirNamesRegex.pattern.matcher(name).matches)
      .flatMap(path => sparkSession.parquet(Some(feedSchema))(path))

    if (!filesDf.isEmpty)
      Some(filesDf.reduce(_ union _))
    else None
 }
```

listPath - custom method for listing data files in hdfs. feedSchema is of StructType

Without if on Some and None I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.reduceLeft
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.reduceLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.reduceLeft(List.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduce(TraversableOnce.scala:208)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.reduce(Traversable.scala:104)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have 3 problems:

1. Seems you can use `==` operator instead of regex matching. You know concrete name of directory to filter, just use filtering by name.
2. As I got your code, `filesDf` is something like `Traversable[DataFrame]`. If you want reduce it safety even this collection is empty you can use `reduceLeftOption` instead of `reduce`.
3. In your `transformDf` method you are trying to filter directory names and reading data using spark, it can be too *heavy* to debug with spark also. I would advise you divide your logic into 2 different methods: first - *read directories* and *filter* them, second - *read* data and `union` them into one general `DataFrame`.

I propose such code samples:

case without dividing logic:

```
def transformDf: Option[DataFrame] = {
  listPath(new Path(feedPath))(fsConfig)
    .map(_.getName)
    .filter(name => name == "_spark_metadata")
    .flatMap(path => sparkSession.parquet(Some(feedSchema))(path))
    .reduceLeftOption(_ union _)
}
```

case with divided logic:

```
def getFilteredPaths: List[String] =
  listPath(new Path(feedPath))(fsConfig)
    .map(_.getName)
    .filter(name => name == "_spark_metadata")

def transformDf: Option[DataFrame] = {
  getFilteredPaths
    .flatMap(path => sparkSession.parquet(Some(feedSchema))(path))
    .reduceLeftOption(_ union _)
}
```

In second way you can write some *light-weight* unit-tests for debug your paths  extraction and when you will have correct paths you can easily read data from directories and union them.